# using pretty faces with web filters

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, prettyfaces

Using Tomcat 7 --- Primefaces 3.4.1 --- javax faces 2.1.17 --- prettyfaces-jsf2 3.3.3

I configured pretty faces on my project correctly but my web filters are not working with new urls which are written by pretty faces.

Here is an example pretty-config.xml

```
<url-mapping id="home">
    <pattern value="/home"/>
    <view-id value="/secure/homepage.xhtml"/>
</url-mapping>

<url-mapping id="register">
    <pattern value="/register"/>
    <view-id value="/public/register.xhtml"/>
</url-mapping>

<url-mapping id="welcome">
    <pattern value="/"/>
    <view-id value="/public/welcome.xhtml"/>
</url-mapping>

<url-mapping id="profile">
    <pattern value="/profile/#{userId}"/>
    <view-id value="/profile.xhtml"/>
</url-mapping>
```

login(welcome) and register pages are in "public" folder, and their web filter is defined with annotation : **@WebFilter("/public/*")**

for my home page in "secure" folder (exactly there will be more pages in the folder), i defined a web filter also and its annotation : **@WebFilter("/secure/*)**

pretty urls are working fine, **but these filters are only working when i write the original urls.**

1) How can i repair my webfilters ?

2) I also want to block user for entering original url. I know that pretty faces is hiding original urls fully but is there a way to do it ?

-- **SOLVED** -- thanks for BalusC

if you defined your filters with annotations, you can configure dispatcher settings like

@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/public/*",  **dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD}**)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PrettyFaces uses like many URL-rewriting solutions [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) to forward the request to the desired target resource.

Servlet filters, when mapped without any `<dispatcher>`, listens by default on "initial" requests only, not on forwarded, included, nor error'ed requests.

So, when you map another servlet filter in `web.xml` *after* the PrettyFaces one, then it would by default not be triggered, unless you explicitly set a `<dispatcher>` on `FORWARD` next to the default of `REQUEST` (you should keep this one for the case PrettyFaces actually doesn't need to perform a forward).

```
<filter-mapping>
    ...
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Or, for the case you're using [`@WebFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html) on your filters, use the [`dispatcherTypes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html#dispatcherTypes%28%29) attribute:

```
@WebFilter(..., dispatcherTypes = { REQUEST, FORWARD })
```

Alternatively, if the filter in question doesn't change the request/response target in any way, e.g. setting the charset, compressing using Gzip, listening on exceptions, etc, then you can also just put it *before* the PrettyFaces one.

Comment: I did not specified any filter in my web.xml, BalusC. Because i am using version="3.0" and pretty is configuring himself automatically as written in documents. Also my web filters are clearly defined with annotations. Have i to define it directly on web.xml for dispatcher settings ?

Comment: thank you @BalusC, it works very well.

@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/public/*",  dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD})

solved my problem. But i want to ask a minor question, updating or refreshing same page (for example using primefaces poll) always catched by filters and its totally normal actually. But Is there a way to escape it ?

Comment: You could map the filter on a more specific URL pattern. Alternatively, if your concern is merely that the filter is dong a relatively expensive job, you could also precheck if it's a JSF ajax request by adding a `if ("partial/ajax".equals(request.getHeader("Faces-Request")))` to do a fast-skip of the whole filter job (just call `FilterChain#doFilter()`).

Comment: I understand my friend, will check it out. Thank you again.